# =IMPORTFEED doesn't load as many items as it instructed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, rss, feed

I am trying to import the feed from the website "https://www.construnario.com/feed" into Google Sheets using the =IMPORTFEED function. However, I have encountered a limitation where it only retrieves 61 results, but I need to retrieve the latest 200 results.

Here is the formula I am currently using:

```
=IMPORTFEED("https://www.construnario.com/feed", "items", FALSE, 200)
```

I have also tried adjusting the LIMIT parameter within the feed URL (https://www.construnario.com/feed?limit=200), but it doesn't seem to affect the number of results returned by the =IMPORTFEED function.

Is there a way to modify the =IMPORTFEED function to retrieve the full 200 results? Or is there an alternative solution or workaround to import the complete feed into Google Sheets? I am using Octoparse to scrape other sites, but since this one doesn't have the dates available on the front-end it makes it impossible to know when they where published.

Is there an alternative to retrieve a long list of items in a RSS? Many RSS readers don't allow you to export to google sheets, which is where I am managing all my data.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You mention: *"I have also tried adjusting the LIMIT parameter within the feed URL (https://www.construnario.com/feed?limit=200), but it doesn't seem to affect the number of results returned"*. This means that **the site will publish only 61 titles** in their feed. Nothing one can do about it.

Comment: In my case I'm only able to get about 30 results, this seems inconsistent, @djur would you mind testing on a different sheet (if possible from a different account) and see if you get the same results there? if you get inconsistent results this might potentially be a bug

Comment: I kept testing and I think @marikamitsos is up to something, although I'm getting different results this seems to be a problem with the feed itself rather than the formula